# How do I select a custom element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have a custom tag as seen below, but can't seem to select it with selector `$("ix:nonNumeric")`. `$("[contextRef]")` works fine, however. What is the correct selector?

```html
<ix:nonNumeric contextRef="PERIOD0" name="se-gen-base:VasentligaHandelserRakenskapsaret" >000</ix:nonNumeric>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the colon in your custom tag:

```
$("ix\\:nonNumeric").text()
```

Example:

```js
console.log( $("ix\\:nonNumeric").text() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ix:nonNumeric contextRef="PERIOD0" name="se-gen-base:VasentligaHandelserRakenskapsaret" >000</ix:nonNumeric>
```

As the docs for [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) states:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`